# Output the result of DF command to variable then print to an HTML page

Tags: bash, html

I am having a problem executing a script that basically captures the disk space from the server and outputs the result to an HTML page.

```
STORAGE=$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n)
```

The output in STDOUT is OK, it is well formatted. When I echo the variable to an HTML page, the output becomes one line, just like this one:

```
/dev/vx/dsk/localdg/wm7x01 vxfs 30G 21G 9.3G 70% /apps/wm7x01 /dev/mapper/vg00-vrts ext3 6.9G 4.7G 2.3G 68% /vrts_install /dev/mapper/vg00-ora11g_cli ext3 7.7G 4.1G 3.3G 57% /usr/oracle11g_cli /dev/mapper/vg00-repackage ext3 1008M 423M 586M 42% /var/spool/repackage /dev/vx/dsk/cfs_dcgnts_dg/shared vxfs 220G 91G 130G 42% /apps/shared
```

I even tried using:

- quotations: `echo "$STORAGE"`
- an array: `echo "{STORAGE[@]}"`

Unfortunately, all yields the same result.

Comment: `echo "$STORAGE"` is fine. There's something wrong in the part of the code you didn't post.

Comment: Are you replacing the line breaks with `<br />` or wrapping the data in `<pre></pre>`?.

Answer (score 3):

How do you echo it? As in

```
$ printf "<pre>%s</pre>\n" "$storage" >> file.html
```

should work.

There should be no need to include `column`. This is a candidate for a HTML table, and could be begotten by something like:

```
df -PTh | \
sed '1d' | \
sort -n -k6 | \
awk '
{
    printf "\n\t<tr>";
    for (n = 1; n < 7; ++n)
            printf("\n\t<td>%s</td>",$n);
    printf "\n\t<td>";
    for(;n <= NF; ++n)
            printf("%s ",$n);
    printf "</td>\n\t</tr>"
}
'
```

Wrap it in something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Disk space usage</title>
<style>
table, td, th {
    border : 1px solid green;
}
th {
    background-color: green;
    color           : white;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Filesystem</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Used</th>
    <th>Avail</th>
    <th>Use%</th>
    <th>Mounted on</th>
    </tr>

<!-- df output awk table -->

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question was closed as unclear, but it seemed very clear to me, as I found this thread because I had the same question. And while the OP never flagged an answer, I just used this answer by @runium as a key component my own script to do exactly what the OP asked. So IMHO, both the question and this answer are good.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap output such as this in a pre block in HTML.

#### Example

```
STORAGE=$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n)
echo "<pre>$STORAGE</pre>"
```

HTML does not take care to preserve white space.

Answer (score 1):

In the output of the command chain is white space in the form of spaces and newlines (and you are lucky there are no tabs). You should make pipe the output into `| sed 's/ /&nbsp;/g' | sed 's/^/<br>/'`:

```
STORAGE=$(df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n)| sed 's/ /&nbsp;/g' | sed 's/^/<br>/'
```

to preserve whitespace. You can use that without getting the font changing effect that `<pre>` induces.

Answer (score 0):

The command substitution is what's butchering your whitespace. From the `bash(1)` man page:

> Bash  performs  the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word  splitting.

Now from my understanding, this means that using

```
STORAGE="$(df ...)"
```

should be enough to preserve all (but trailing) whitespace. However, I tried both versions and whitespace is totally messed up. Instead, why not just use output redirection:

```
df -PTh | column -t | sort -n -k6n >> /your/html/file
```

along with the filters suggested by the other answers to preserve whitespace in the rendered HTML page.